# Trouble selecting a pandas DataFrame in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a Django project of which the code is rather complex. For that reason I split it into several files which are called from models.py. But because the code is complex I would like to run the code stand-alone to debug it.

I have a simple piece of code that looks like this:

```
print('DF:\n', df)
selection = df[df[sel_crit] >= sel_val]
print('SELECTION\n', selection)
```

In the examples below: `sel_crit` is "Coverage" and `sel_val` is 0.1. The value of df is (first print statement):

```
DF:
            cpu  Status  Coverage    Distance   Lyapunov  FractDim  Missers  Uninteresting                     Coefficients
28    0.067678     1.0  0.107931   95.987910        NaN  0.569875      0.0            0.0  IQLHUFOFBKCJGUSQGPJPTPNUDPMTPAU
304   0.124464     1.0  0.107508   93.144860   0.032726       NaN      0.0            0.0  IUMOUMOGSHJIIPPPCNCCOJLHQFPZHPU
1241  0.123443     1.0  0.107392   82.698345  26.796081  0.999999      0.0            0.0  ILGDKLOSWHPJIPPPCTBITJLLQLPLCUM
117   0.123463     1.0  0.106203   80.419825  -0.862029  0.602059      0.0            0.0  ILJEHSNGNHGGIJJLFNJPOBAUDQALHUM
386   0.131001     1.0  0.102985   73.330918  -3.630947       NaN      0.0            0.0  INTDEKECMIQPLKELOBHJHLREUDGKAMG
1117  0.125086     1.0  0.096597   79.500703  -0.793354  0.371611      0.0            0.0  IKHRKQQPAEGLLCBFFPCQPROBUMLGCOH
797   0.123657     1.0  0.094546   97.020646   0.828907  1.204119      0.0            0.0  IGXYLPLFCHSPMHHDMFCREMMPAWPUFQL
356   0.126138     1.0  0.091071   88.329201  -0.361238  1.414972      0.0            0.0  IKKQLLHCNLGLLSHLEPIQCIGKKDHTFBH
675   0.123957     1.0  0.072746  103.955944  15.489624  1.531477      0.0            0.0  IQUAUIFLCCQPZKHYIGLOHMHSONMXCPW
182   0.123799     1.0  0.065901   63.458365  -0.523814  1.903088      0.0            0.0  ITMBUJLNUOMGTVNDPNJVOCNUDSMTMIU
```

The results produced by the Djando runserver:

```
SELECTION
       cpu  Status  Coverage  Distance  Lyapunov  FractDim  Missers  Uninteresting Coefficients
28    NaN     NaN  0.107931       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN            NaN          NaN
304   NaN     NaN  0.107508       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN            NaN          NaN
1241  NaN     NaN  0.107392       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN            NaN          NaN
117   NaN     NaN  0.106203       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN            NaN          NaN
386   NaN     NaN  0.102985       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN            NaN          NaN
1117  NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN            NaN          NaN
797   NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN            NaN          NaN
356   NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN            NaN          NaN
675   NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN            NaN          NaN
182   NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN            NaN          NaN
```

The normal output is (by running the code stand alone in python):

```
SELECTION
            cpu  Status  Coverage    Distance   Lyapunov  FractDim  Missers  Uninteresting                     Coefficients
28    0.067678     1.0  0.107931   95.987910        NaN  0.569875      0.0            0.0  IQLHUFOFBKCJGUSQGPJPTPNUDPMTPAU
304   0.124464     1.0  0.107508   93.144860   0.032726       NaN      0.0            0.0  IUMOUMOGSHJIIPPPCNCCOJLHQFPZHPU
1241  0.123443     1.0  0.107392   82.698345  26.796081  0.999999      0.0            0.0  ILGDKLOSWHPJIPPPCTBITJLLQLPLCUM
117   0.123463     1.0  0.106203   80.419825  -0.862029  0.602059      0.0            0.0  ILJEHSNGNHGGIJJLFNJPOBAUDQALHUM
386   0.131001     1.0  0.102985   73.330918  -3.630947       NaN      0.0            0.0  INTDEKECMIQPLKELOBHJHLREUDGKAMG
```

With different values for dataframe I get the same sort of result. The stand alone version yields correct results and the Django version wrong results.

All code resides in the <app> directory of the <project> directory. The stand alone code consists of a main program, that runs the code in the <app> directory. The code in the <app> directory is called by models.py.

I cannot explain why the Django output is so completely wrong. Can anyone explain what's happening here and better, how I can get correct results from the server?

**Update**

It was a mistake of mine of course and I am sorry so have associated Django with a bug, I have changed the title of the question to avoid this association. The variable `sel_crit` was defined in a form and it was a `SelectMultiple` of all columns in the `DataFrame`. Because of that it is a list, not being `'Coverage'` but `['Coverage']`. It took me quite some time to realise that is was a list I was staring at and not a string.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on a clean Django install. Could you also try it in a new empty Django project? Do you use the same Python environment for the Django and the stand alone script?

Comment: @Dauros, thanks for trying. I see if I can duplicate the error in a small setting. Should have dome that before.

Comment: @Dauros, did as you suggested, couldn't replicate it at all. Found the solution at last and adjusted title and added an update. Thanks for your suggestions.